# Clarification on `this` keyword in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala, and is trying to follow the [tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/classes.html) on the documentation. I understand that `this` is used to 'access' a class' methods or fields, but on this code block, this is called as without any 'option' but it default to call the 'toString' method.

Here's the code block i'm talking about

```scala
class Person(var firstName: String, var lastName: String) {

    println("the constructor begins")

    // 'public' access by default
    var age = 0

    // some class fields
    private val HOME = System.getProperty("user.home")

    // some methods
    override def toString(): String = s"$firstName $lastName is $age years old"

    def printHome(): Unit = println(s"HOME = $HOME")    
    def printFullName(): Unit = println(this) 

    printHome()
    printFullName()
    println("you've reached the end of the constructor")

}
```

Output in REPLL:

```scala
scala> val p = new Person("Kim", "Carnes")
the constructor begins
HOME = /Users/al
Kim Carnes is 0 years old
you've reached the end of the constructor
p: Person = Kim Carnes is 0 years old
```

Comment: `println` calls the `toString` method of whatever is passed to it. So the object itself was passed to the `prinrln` function which then called `toString` to it. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Bro thank you. This makes sense now. I just tried removing the override method, and became more clear. Appreciate it mate thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Luis. His answer:

*println calls the toString method of whatever is passed to it. So the object itself was passed to the println function which then called toString to it. Does that makes sense?*

Basically, `println(this)` has the same output when you call `println(p)`.